# brought changes with git pull, but I don't see them staged

Tags: java, eclipse, git, version-control, github

I have a local branch `L1`. It origins from remote `R1`.

then I made it trackable with `R2`.

Now i want to pull `R1` to --> `L1`

I used `source tree` software to git pull.

I see there are changes, as `L1` is 41 changes ahead `R2`

but i don't see them anywhere: no in the UI nor with git status cmd.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by see the changes? They won't be staged if you pulled they will have been committed.  Also not sure what `github` and `java` have to do with your question consider removing those tags :-)

What does git log show you? does that log have the commits in it?

Comment: 41 new commits introduced because of the merge?